# Postgresql muda letra com acento

Tags: php, postgresql

Vejam eu estou salvando dados no *SGBD PostgreSQL*, só que os dados (NOME, CIDADE, RUA), eu estou salvando em maiúsculo para facilitar na hora de pesquisar.

Ele está salvando normal, o problema é que, quando eu salvo uma palavra em maiúsculo e com acento, o *PostgreSQL* transforma a letra em minúsculo.

```
  $nome = strtoupper($cliente->getNome());
        $cpf = $cliente->getCpf();
        $endereco = $cliente->getEndereco();
        $cidade = strtoupper($endereco->getCidade());
        $rua = strtoupper($endereco->getRua());
        $numero = $endereco->getNumero();
        $telefones = $cliente->getTelefones();
        $telefone1 = $telefones[0];
        $telefone2 = $telefones[1];

      $valorArmazenar = $this->conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente(nome_cliente,cidade, rua, numero, telefone1, telefone2, cpf) VALUES(:nome,:cidade,:rua,:numero,:telefone1,:telefone2, :cpf)");

      $valorArmazenar->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
      $valorArmazenar->bindValue(":cidade", $cidade);
      $valorArmazenar->bindValue(":rua", $rua);
      $valorArmazenar->bindValue(":numero",$numero);
      $valorArmazenar->bindValue(":telefone1", $telefone1);
      $valorArmazenar->bindValue(":telefone2", $telefone2);
      $valorArmazenar->bindValue(":cpf", $cpf);
      $valorArmazenar->execute();
```

Vejam que o "Ã" da palavra JOÃO ele deixou JOãO "ã" em minúsculo, e isso dificulta na hora da minha pesquisa pelo registro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o CHARSET  da tabela?

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJarouche o charset é utf-8

Comment: Acredito que `$valorArmazenar->bindValue(":nome", mb_substr($nome));` resolve o problema ;)

Comment: Rodrigo, a resposta do Edson abaixo vai te ajudar. Indepente disso, eu sugiro a leitura deste artigo:   (Não ligue por que o titulo parece ofensivo - o cnteudo é muito importante) http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o strtoupper não conseguiu transformar a letra acentuada para maiúsculo, neste caso use o [mb_strtoupper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php) no lugar.

```
$nome      = mb_strtoupper($cliente->getNome(), 'UTF-8');
$cpf       = $cliente->getCpf();
$endereco  = $cliente->getEndereco();
$cidade    = mb_strtoupper($endereco->getCidade(), 'UTF-8');
$rua       = mb_strtoupper($endereco->getRua(), 'UTF-8');
$numero    = $endereco->getNumero();
$telefones = $cliente->getTelefones();
$telefone1 = $telefones[0];
$telefone2 = $telefones[1];
```

Clique [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.mbstring.php) para entender mais sobre o caso.

#### Dica

Sempre que possível crie seu banco de dados no ENCODING `UTF8`, LC_COLLATE `en_US.UTF-8` e LC_CTYPE `en_US.UTF-8`, caso contrário você poderá ter esse tipo de problema e outros como ordenar uma query alfabética e ele trazer primeiro as que começam com letras minúsculas e depois as que começam com letras maiúsculas (ou o oposto, não me lembro).

Answer (score -1):

Se o seu PostgreSQL tiver suporte ao chartset LATIN1, apenes recrie o banco de dados com as seguintes características:

```
    CREATE DATABASE nome_do_banco ENCODING 'LATIN1' LC_COLLATE 'pt_BR.ISO-8859-1' LC_CTYPE 'pt_BR.ISO-8859-1' template template0;
```

Faça o teste novamente e veja como ficou.

Comment: Não recomende isso antes de saber como o sujeito configurou o ambiente de desenvolvimento. Mudar o _charset_ do banco reflete em cadeia: servidor web, php, codificação dos scripts, etc.

Comment: é verdade, criei um DataBase padrão do postgresql

Comment: Você não resolve um problema com caracteres internacionais chutando codificações para usar. Tem que entender o que está acontecendo. Em particular, o uso de LATIN1 só vai complicar se houverem caracteres que não estão definidos nessa codificação.

Ademais, o problema nesse caso é claramente do lado PHP, não no Postgres